# No module named 'py2neo.internal.http'

Tags: python, neo4j, anaconda

I'm trying to install py2neo in Jupyter NB, but I'm getting always this error.
Can someone please advise what's causing this?

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph(auth=("neo4j", "neo4j"))
```

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> C:\anaconda\anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database.py in **new**(cls, uri, **settings)
>
> KeyError: 'fa2204be4082b5a388ff8b58e1db2944'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 1 from py2neo import Graph
> ----> 2 graph = Graph(auth=("neo4j", "neo4j"))
> 3
>
> C:\anaconda\anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database.py in **new**(cls, uri, **settings)
>
> C:\anaconda\anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database.py in **new**(cls, uri, **settings)
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2neo.internal.http'

Comment: Have you installed `py2neo` with pip?  `pip install py2neo`

Comment: Yeah, I did that. py2neo 2020.0.0 was installed.

Comment: Don't install anything in the conda base environment and certainly not with pip. Don't add the Anconda folder to the PATH and certainly not to the PYTHONPATH. Conda is self contained. And most important: Don't forget to ACTIVATE a conda environment before you are going to use it.